# Trouble installing dropbox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

I am having so much trouble installing dropbox on my machine running ubuntu 14.04. The "dropbox set up" dialog box shows up with a `No internet connection' message.

I have set the proxies under "dropbox icon (greyed) -> Preferences" and I know that this is correct. Still the icon reads: `Waiting to be linked to a dropbox account`. I already spent three solid days trying to set this right and tried out all possible dropbox installations too.

Can someone please help me with this?

Additionally, here is the message that appears on the terminal:

```
** (dropbox:5969): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I have double checked that there is no firewall blocking dropbox and the internet connection works great.

Comment: The accessibility bus warning is not a problem. However, Dropbox is a proprietary service and not part of Ubuntu. You probably need to contact Dropbox's support staff to get help with using their product and your account.

Answer (score 0):

lets hope this may work.

https://www.dropbox.com/help/72

if its an inaccessible due to a permissions problem

```
Quit Dropbox by right-clicking on the Dropbox menu from the menu bar and selecting Quit
Open a terminal window and copy and paste the following line into the terminal (exactly as written below):

sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox
sudo chattr -R -i ~/Dropbox
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox


If your Dropbox folder is not ~/Dropbox, make sure you modify all the commands above to point to the correct location.
Restart Dropbox by going to the Internet menu under Applications.
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. In my case, I am just installing Dropbox on this machine. So, I do not have a ~/Dropbox folder even created in the first place. I am not sure how to check if it is due to a permissions problem giving trouble here.